# Sync MkDocs to Azure DevOps WIKI

Tags: azure-devops, mkdocs, azure-devops-wiki

Our team is writing their documentation all in mkdocs and this also contains autogenerated content as well. Is there a way we can sync mkdocs markdown docs to azure devops wiki? I am pretty new to azure wiki and the project management is adamant of wanting to have the docs in azure wiki as well and I like to automate the process! The repo is in github which contains the mkdocs markdown files. Any idea how I can do this?

The mkdocs contains image attachments as well. There are also autogenerated content as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, I was finally able to find a solution that worked for me.

The solution is available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/legendof-selda/b7374700ec588bde4012954527c146e2)

the gist of it is to create a wiki repo and push your markdown files there but making sure it follows the [azure devops wiki guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-file-structure?view=azure-devops)!